# First match in a collection

Tags: c#, linq

I want to convert this code to a linq solution. What it does it looks into a collection of customers and see if at least one of the has a middle name. This code works fine, I'm just trying to learn linq, so looking for an alternative solution.:

```
//Customers - List<Customer>
private bool checkMiddleName()
{
    foreach (Customer i in Customers)
    {
        if (i.HasMiddleName == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I tried to write something like: `(Customers.Foreach(x=>x.HasMiddleName==true)...`
but looks line it's not the method I'm looking for.

Comment: FYI -- the ForEach method on List just executes the given function on each member of the list

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you just want to know if theres at least one, you can use `Enumerable.Any`:

```
bool atLeastOneCustomerWithMiddleName = Customers.Any(c => c.HasMiddleName);
```

If you want to know the first matching customer, you can use `Enumerable.First` or [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) to find the first customer with `MiddleName==true`:

```
var customer = Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.HasMiddleName);
if(customer != null)
{
    // there is at least one customer with HasMiddleName == true
}
```

`First`  throws an InvalidOperationException if the source sequence is empty, whereas `FirstOrDefault` returns `null` if there's no match.

Comment: Any way to return true or false from the query?

Answer (score 3):

```
var result   = Customers.Where(x=>x.HasMiddleName == true).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on this:

> What it does it looks into a collection of customers and see if at least one of the has a middle name.

Try

```
return Customers.Where(x => x.HasMiddleName).Any();
```

This query return `true` if at least one custmer has the property `HasMiddleName = true`

Comment: `Any` takes a predicate, so you can shorten this to `return Customers.Any(x => x.HasMiddleName);`

Answer (score -2):

You may use the following to achieve what you need:

```
Customers.Where(cust=> cust.HasMiddleName).Count > 0
```

So , if Count is more than zero means you have some customers who have Middle name.

Or for better performance you may say:

```
bool customerWithMiddleName;

foreach(Customer cust in Customers)
{
  if(cust.HasMiddleName)
  {
    customerWithMiddleName = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not a good idea since it executes the whole query, only to know if there's one matching element. Consider that Customers contains 1000000 customers and the first has a middlename. `Any(cust=> cust.HasMiddleName)` would return `true` immediately whereas your approach would check each and every element before it returns.

Comment: This requires the code to count how many correct items there are, rather than short-circuiting the first time a match is found. It could be unnecessarily expensive. Better to use .Any().