# How to find first occurrence in c# list without going over entire list with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list: `var strings = new List<string>();`

My list contains 5 strings.

```
 string.Add("Paul");
 string.Add("Darren");
 string.Add("Joe");
 string.Add("Jane");
 string.Add("Sally");
```

I want to iterate over the list and as soon as I find a string that begins with "J", I do not need to continue processing the list.

Is this possible with LINQ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you gone through the list of LINQ methods to see if any seem to accomplish this goal?  To directly answer your question yes, it's possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [First match in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570283/first-match-in-a-collection)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
strings.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.StartsWith("J"));
```

And also if you are new to LINQ I'd recommend going through [101 LINQ Samples in C#.](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx):

```
var firstMatch = strings.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith("J"));
if(firstMatch != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(firstMatch);
}
```

[**demo**](http://ideone.com/TPOM13)

Answer (score 3):

```
bool hasJName = strings.Any(x => x.StartsWith("J"));
```

This checks to see if any names that start with J exist.

```
string jName = strings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("J"));
```

This returns the first name that starts with J. If no names starting with J are found, it returns `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb291976%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) LINQ method (in `System.Linq`):

```
strings.First(e => e.StartsWith("J"));
```

Or `FirstOrDefault` if you are not sure that any element in your list will satisfy the condition:

```
strings.FirstOrDefault(e => e.StartsWith("J"));
```

Then, it returns `null` if no element has been found.