# C# - How to return user(object) from a list of users(objects), if user input matches email and password of that object

Tags: c#, list, class, object

Trying to create a login function to return user from a list of users if the inputted information matches the user.

Currently have a list of users with each user having a name, email and password.

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();

// my user register function
public User Register_User(string a_name, string a_email, string a_pwd)
{
    User user = new User(a_name, a_email, a_pwd);
    users.Add(user);
    return user;
}

// the login function trying to implement
public void login()
{
    string email;
    string pwd;

    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter your email address");
    email = Console.Readline();

    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter your password");
    pwd = Console.Readline();

    // check if email and pwd matches a user in users
    // return the user

}
```

I'm just not sure on how to check if both of the user input matches a user in a list of users and return the user.

Comment: Use LINQ's `.FirstOrDefault` or `.SingleOrDefault` (the SingleOrDefault option may be bad for large lists as it has to not only find the first match, but also ensure that there are no other matches). [Another SO question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570283/first-match-in-a-collection)

Comment: I'd suggest a `Dictionary<string, User>` with a normalised form e-mail address, but since this is evidently a small project it's probably not worth the optimisation, and if it were a real project you'd be using a database anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the solutions that you've suggested. I thought the solution would be kinda like `foreach (User user in users) if (email and password matches the user) return user`, and I'm just not sure how to implement the if part.

Comment: If you look at the link provided above you will find how the OP used a normal foreach loop to check a property of the current object. In your case you need to check two properties and thus you need a && logical operator. But today code usually remove the explicit foreach loop and replaces it with the LINQ approach using the .FirstOrDefault extension. The loop is still there but it is hidden inside the .FirstOrDefault method

Comment: I should of mentioned that I am very new to c# and just couldnt quite understand just from a single line of code. I kinda understand the FirstOrDefault now with the solution that user9389481 has provided. Thanks though for providing information.

Comment: Sorry. I replied and went out. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple** :-
Use `FirstOrDefault` to find the user, and return it.

```
public User login()
{
    string email;
    string pwd;

    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter your email address");
    email = Console.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;

    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter your password");
    pwd = Console.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;

    // check if email and pwd matches a user in users
    var user = users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email.Equals(email));
    if (user == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to find any user!");

    // return the user
    return user;
}
```

**Better alternative** :-
Use a dictionary to store users, and find the user in O(1) at runtime.

```
Dictionary<string, User> users = new Dictionary<string, User>();

// my user register function
public User Register_User(string a_name, string a_email, string a_pwd)
{
    User user = new User(a_name, a_email, a_pwd);
    users.Add(a_email, user);
    return user;
}

// the login function trying to implement
public User login()
{
    string email;
    string pwd;

    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter your email address");
    email = Console.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;

    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter your password");
    pwd = Console.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;

    // check if email and pwd matches a user in users
    if (users.ContainsKey(email))
    {
        // return the user
        return users[email];
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to find any user!");
}
```

**Note** :-
I would suggest storing users in the database and using a data context, or repository pattern to find the user. This will delegate the task of finding the user to the database, where it should ideally belong.

Comment: Thanks for that, I just needed to see it before understanding how it works.

Comment: Mostly correct. You just need to add the check for password also.